# added a local external JAR file. Now application runs locally, but gives ClassNotFoundException from docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, maven-3

I have added an external JAR in pom.xml. It works fine , but throws ClassNotFoundException when run in a docker container.

Pom.xml snippet :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>external.group_name</groupId>
            <artifactId>external-java-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/External_Jar_name.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Docker commands:

docker build -t $(BUILDER_TAG) -f $(BUILD_DOCKERFILE_NAME) .

@docker run -v m2:/root/.m2 -v `pwd`:/build $(BUILDER_TAG)

docker build -t $(IMAGE_TAG) .

docker run -it -e ENVIRONMENT_NAME=local -e REGION_NAME=local -e JVM_OPTIONS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=4000" -p 8080:8080 -p 4000:4000 $(IMAGE_TAG)

Comment: You check the jar in the docker system? With the same path?

Comment: What is your `run` command? How do you execute the application in the container?

Comment: @saqibAhmed : edited the question to answer your question

Comment: @P3Ri : In the container there is only one application.jar , which I think will be containing the external JAR.

Comment: Also, I tried to see the contents of application.JAR inside container, and it doesn't have the content of the external JAR. However, when I create the JAR locally, using mvn clean package; it does have them.